# Order tags by number of posts they are used in?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one called `Tags`, the other called `Posts_Tags` for a many-to-many relationship. The `Posts_Tags` contains two columns, `postid` and `tagid`. The `Tags` database also contains an `id` column, which corresponds to the `tagid` in the joint table.

I'd like to get a list of tag names to display to the user, ordered by the number of times they are used. Using this information, I've constructed a query which joins the two tables together:

```
SELECT Tags.name FROM `Tags` LEFT JOIN `Posts_Tags` ON Tags.id = Posts_Tags.tagid
```

This gets me a list of tag names, but obviously, it doesn't do much more than just selecting data purely from the `Tags` table. I know I need to add an `ORDER BY` clause somewhere (and possibly a `GROUP BY`, but I'm not sure how to construct the query.

What should I add to this query to successfully sort my results by the number of posts each tag is used in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group By` To count the number of times each tag is used. This assumes your tag names are unique, if not you'll want to group on the id instead.

```
Select
  t.Name,
  Count(*) as TagUse
From
  Tags t
    Left Join
  Post_Tags p
    On t.Id = p.TagID
Group By
  t.Name
Order By
  TagUse Desc
```

Comment: +1 but FWIW it'd be better to give the `COUNT(*)` an alias and ORDER BY the alias.  The ORDER BY *ordinal* is deprecated SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that one tag can be used just once on a post, you can do:

```
SELECT Tags.ID, Tags.name, count(*) as NumPosts
FROM Tags
  LEFT JOIN Posts_Tags ON Tags.id = Posts_Tags.tagid
Group by Tags.ID, Tags.name
Order by 3 desc
```